# Main menu, footer, right menu not showing up on default page

Tags: joomla-2.5

Inside the template manager, I have selected a bunch of pages for main menu, top header, right menu. However, the website loads just the default Home page article without these menus. Any tips on debugging this problem? Joomla version is 2.5. I am completely unfamiliar with its working, any help is much appreciated! Do let me know if I should provide any additional details.

Comment: Joomla2.5 is very outdated now. Are you able to upgrade your Joomla version or is there a technical blocker?

Comment: Thank you! I am afraid that upgrading is not an option for me